# URL Rewrite with Query String

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, query-string, url-rewrite-module

I am writing a rewrite rule in IIS with type Redirect. I want the new url to have a query string parameter value added newly to it. The old url does not have any query string values.

What is the best way to achieve this?

**Old url: abc.com/2017/Sample-Page**

**New Url: test.abc.com/2017/Sample-Page?redirect=y**

```
<rule name="rewrite with query string" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)2017/Sample-Page(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="abc.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://test.abc.com/{R:0}?redirect=y"/>
  </rule>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append query string & value via IIS rewrite rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311213/how-to-append-query-string-value-via-iis-rewrite-rule)

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. Moreover there are no query string in my original url

Comment: Your sample above is showing a "Rewrite" not a "Redirect" are you sure that is not the problem?

Comment: I was trying few things. It is supposed to be Redirect. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
<rule name="rewrite with query string" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)2017/Sample-Page(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="abc.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://test.abc.com/{R:0}?redirect=y"/>
  </rule>
```

Comment: This is the same rewrite rule that you had in your question. What changed to fix your problem?