# Adding random query string parameter to URL on IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, urlrewriting.net

I am hosting our website on `IIS 8.5 on windows 2012 server`. The application is a nodejs based application. It has index.html as the entry point.

`What I want is:` Whenever index.html is requested, I want to append a random string to this page. The idea is to bust the cache by appending query string.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? Should I use URL rewrite module? I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311213/how-to-append-query-string-value-via-iis-rewrite-rule) . This guy is adding some static query string. I want to add some dynamic/random query string. It could be time stamp or anything.

Comment: Have you looked into creating a custom rewrite provider?  I would not say this is "simple", but you could probably append the last modified timestamp to a URL using one: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module