# How do I embed javascript into an IIS UrlRewrite rule?

Tags: javascript, iis, url-rewriting

Context: Azure, Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8

The standard rewrite providers in IIS 8 are `{` and '}' and these are used in various contexts to represent captures, replacements and symbols, e.g. `{C:0}`, `{R:1}`, `{HTTP_ORIGIN}`.

I'm trying to use a rule to inject Google Tag Manager markup into a page.

```xml
<rule name="Inject GTM After HEAD" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true">
  <match filterByTags="None" pattern="&lt;head.*?>" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}&lt;!-- Google Tag Manager --> &lt;script>(function(w,d,s,l,i) { w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push( { 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js' } );var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&amp;l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src= 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f); } )(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');&lt;/script> &lt;!-- End Google Tag Manager -->" />
</rule>
```

This does *NOT* work as the JavaScript contains `{` and IIS's UrlRewrite tool immediately complains with a yellow box reading `The rewrite provider " w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push( { 'gtm.start'" does not exist` (note that it terminates at the `:` which would separate the usual `R` or `C` from the numeric qualifier.)

I have tried swapping `{` with `&#123;` but this doesn't work well, giving me the following in the generated web page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head><!-- Google Tag Manager --> <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i) &#123; w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push( &#123; 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js' } );var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src= 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f); } )(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script> <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Naturally the browser complains about dodgy JavaScript code.

IIS has been around for a long time. I expect the solution is obvious to someone. What is the usual thing to do to make inclusion of JavaScript possible?

**LATER**

It has been suggested that I google with the word "inject". Cool idea. Results?

1. [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-outbound-rules-to-add-web-analytics-tracking-code) demonstrates how to insert a JavaScript comment.
2. [Webtuna](https://www.webtuna.com/using-microsoft-url-rewriter-inject-webtuna-js-iis-site/) demonstrates how to inject a reference to an online resource, but not a slab of JavaScript code. This would work fine if it wasn't for the fact that I'm trying to embed a GTM block.
3. [EG Innovations](https://www.eginnovations.com/documentation/The-eG-Real-User-Monitor/Instrumenting-a-Web-Site-or-Web-Application-on-IIS-using-URL-Rewrite.htm) has lots of good info but again the code sample provided doesn't contain braces.

Comment: Try searching for `inject` instead:   [iis rewrite inject javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=iis+rewrite+inject+javascript)

Comment: Would it be an option to use a query parameter and on the redirected-to page conditionally display the JS you want?

Comment: Thanks for the idea @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁. Can you demonstrate or point me toward a demonstration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have documented the procedure I used at [DEV](https://dev.to/bugmagnet/using-urlrewrite-to-inject-scripts-into-web-pages-49).

Essentially, we put the GTM code in a js file on a different subdomain and embed a script tag with a src pointing at that js file.

Answer (score 2):

I would append a query string and on the redirected-to page conditionally include the JS you want.

So, you'd have something similar to (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18350851/5675325))

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect for download result page" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)/test.aspx(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/test.aspx?rf=sp" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="flag=value" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Then, in your redirected page, have something like this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26979784/5675325) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4597085/5675325))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("flag=value") > -1)) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML += ("<script src=\"...\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>");
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a simpler more generic solution to URI encode the script body and then use `eval`?

e.g.

To execute an arbitrary script such as `(function(){console.log("hello");})()`

obtain the encoded version...

`encodeURIComponent("(function(){console.log(\"hello\");})()")`

(Note that I have escaped `"`s within the script necessarily here in the string argument to `encodeURI`)

Output of the above is `'(function()%7Bconsole.log(%22hello%22);%7D)()'`

Note there are no `{`s or `}`s in this version

Can we now pass into the rewrite rule a script such as...

`eval(decodeURIComponent('(function()%7Bconsole.log(%22hello%22)%3B%7D)()'))`

Obviously this is using the "dreaded" `eval` - However as we are in complete control (on the server itself) and passing a static string of our choosing - I believe this is a valid use of `eval` for the sake of this workaround.

This solution does not require any hosting of a `js` file elsewhere etc.

I think this will also encode/decode `:`s